# Reading parameter inputs from a txt/csv file to run a command in loop (windows batch)

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

Kindly excuse me if it seems a bit amateur. I'm not so good with windows batch files.

I am using Instaloader to download single posts. Instaloader can take an input with a content ID. I am trying to write a batch file so that it can take content IDs as an input from a csv file and download it in a loop.

Here is my sample which works but I have to input an ID every time. I would like it to take the ID from a csv file until it finishes all the rows.

```
@echo off
:prompt
set /p post= "Enter ID: "
instaloader --no-metadata-json --no-compress-json --no-captions --dirname-pattern={profile} --filename-pattern {profile}_{date_utc} -- -%post%
echo.
goto prompt
```

I should use FOR I believe but I just couldn't get it work. Thanks for any suggestions.

I tried a few samples of using FOR but it just fails. I am not sure if there is a better approach to this. I don't mind using powershell if it can be done in a more efficient way like using Import-CSV first.

The PS attempt:

```
foreach ($post in Get-Content '.\IG Posts.txt') 
{
 do { instaloader --no-metadata-json --no-compress-json --no-captions --dirname-pattern={profile} --filename-pattern {profile}_{date_utc} -- -$post } while (eol) 
}
```

Sample txt/csv (they are actual content IDs that instaloader would download:

```
Cm4AoMVy60x
Cm0UMTAyLJe
ClViwoRStoa
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use batch files for things like this? On the long run it might be a good idea to use powershell instead...

Comment: Thanks. I tried powershell as well. It's only a personal project so batch files is sufficient. In PS, how do I run instaloader.exe in a loop for each id from the txt file?

foreach ($post in Get-Content '.\IG Posts.txt') 
{
 do { instaloader --no-metadata-json --no-compress-json --no-captions --dirname-pattern={profile} --filename-pattern {profile}_{date_utc} -- -$post } while (eof) 
}

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and submit, into a code box, some example content directly from your CSV file, so that we can reproduce your task, and offer a focused solution.

Comment: @Compo I am unable to code box to comments but I will edit and add the PS code that I attempted and sample txt/csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Theoretical and untried]

```
@echo off
setlocal
if "%~1"=="" echo Syntax %0 "filename containing list"&goto :eof
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("%~1") do instaloader --no-metadata-json --no-compress-json --no-captions --dirname-pattern={profile} --filename-pattern {profile}_{date_utc} -- -%%b
goto :eof
```

where this batch should be invoked as 
*thisbatch* "filename"

`%1` is the first parameter on the command line. `%~1` is the same, minus any enclosing quotes. "%~1" is the (first paramater - enclosing quotes) enclosed in quotes.

In the `for /f` line, the `usebackq` means "the thing in quotes is a filename" and `delims=` means "there are no delimiters on the lines of the file".

So each line of the files is assigned to `%%b` in turn and `instaloader` is run using the contents of the line.

Note that if `instaloader` is a batch file, you should use `call instaloader...`

I'm assuming a textfile contains the required data, one to a line. If you want otherwise, please post a sample.

Comment: This worked out for me. Thank you Magoo. I made a slight change so I dont need to invoke the batch. Instead, just reads through the txt file and download. Many thanks again.